# Contact Entry in Eloqua & the journey it involves?

Tags: database, salesforce, crm, eloqua, journey

Once a contact enters Eloqua via list upload (or) Form Submission ( or) Webvisits -
what is the journey of contact activities taken place - Eg : he will be Globally Subscribed , in CDO the contact undergoes Global Privacy check - apart from these - how is the life cycle of Contact will be carried in Eloqua - what are all the System process taken place to turn the contact as a valid in Eloqua DB ?

Comment: Can you be more specific to the problem. i.e., What you have tried and what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring updating/existing contacts, not much happens when a new contact is created in Eloqua.

Out of the box, Eloqua is a pretty clean slate. When a contact is created, their

- creation and modified dates are timestamped
- subscription status is the default "subscribed globally"
- email address is "valid" (based on bouncebacks)

The only requirement to create a contact is an email address, and that's it. What happens after is business specific and has to be explicitly defined. Are there any listeners triggered based on contact creation or form submission? What form processing steps are configured? Do any of these steps then send the contact to an integration? If there are any active lead scoring models they will run through those and have a score assigned.

Anything outside of the creation of the record, is completely custom and varies by business. Eloqua does not impose any particular subscription, privacy, stage, status, or lifecycle paradigm, that's up to you to define and align with your processes.